# Run a bootstrap action on an existing job flow

Tags: python, hadoop, bootstrapping, elastic-map-reduce

I have a job flow with keep-alive set, on which I want to run several bootstrap actions. One such action is a script that builds and installs Python 3.3.

However the `elastic-mapreduce` CLI only allows for bootstrap actions to be run during job flow creation.

Is there some way to modify the environment after it's already created?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately bootstrap actions can only be run before Hadoop starts and before the node begins processing data as explained in [the bootstrap actions documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/Bootstrap.html).

Amazon is pretty open regarding new features though, so if you have a solid use case, I would advise to post it on their forums, and they might just turn it into a feature :)